# Declare a cursor to use it after begin

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a project where i have to check if how many products are left to sell from a company for certain clients. A client can have many companies, also i have to refuse when a client or a product don't exist.

I have a table where i have clients and companies, then i got another where i have companies and products. I'm trying to create cursors to manage on the "companie-product" table, just the companies that the client can buy from, but when i declare a cursor it says "it's not a cursor" i've tryed the %rowtype, also the %type, and neither work. Does anyone know how i can fix it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Transaccion
IS
   my_cantidaRechazada   NUMBER;

   CURSOR peti
   IS
        SELECT idCliente, idProducto, cantidadPedido
          FROM TABLAS_COMP.peticiones
      ORDER BY idCliente ASC;

   CURSOR empresaCliente
   IS
        SELECT *
          FROM TABLAS_CL.empresacliente
      ORDER BY tablas_cl.empresacliente.empresa;

   empC                  empresaCliente%ROWTYPE;

   CURSOR empresaProducto (vempresa NUMBER)
   IS
        SELECT *
          FROM TABLAS_PRO.empresaproducto
         WHERE empresa = vempresa
      ORDER BY tablas_pro.empresaproducto.empresa ASC;

   empP                  empresaProducto%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   FOR cont IN peti
   LOOP
      IF existecliente (cont.idCliente) = 0
      THEN
         my_cantidaRechazada := cont.cantidadPedido;

         INSERT INTO TABLAS_COMP.rechazados
              VALUES (cont.idCliente,
                      cont.idProducto,
                      cont.cantidadPedido,
                      my_cantidaRechazada);
      ELSIF existeproducto (cont.idProducto) = 0
      THEN
         my_cantidaRechazada := cont.cantidadPedido;

         INSERT INTO TABLAS_COMP.RECHAZADOS
              VALUES (cont.idCliente,
                      cont.idProducto,
                      cont.cantidadPedido,
                      my_cantidaRechazada);
      END IF;

        SELECT *
          INTO empC
          FROM TABLAS_CL.empresacliente
         WHERE Cliente = cont.idCliente
      ORDER BY empresa ASC;


      FOR empP IN empC
      LOOP -- (here's where the error is showed, it says "empC it's not a cursor")
         SELECT *
           INTO empP
           FROM TABLAS_PRO.empresaproducto
          WHERE Empresa = empC.Empresa;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END Transaccion;
```

Thanks in advance, David.

Comment: *it says "empC it's not a cursor"* - well, it isn't. Check the declaration of `empC`.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you specified oracle error *exactly*, along with the `ORA-XXXXX` error code. Saying it in your words can be ambiguous.

Anyway: what you indicated is wrong, really. Should be

```
-- wrong: for empP in empC loop
for empP in empresaProducto loop
   ...
end loop;
```

because `empP` is declared as `empresaProducto` cursor variable.

Though, `SELECT` you put into the loop is meaningless - you already have `empP`, so - why would you insert into it again? Think it over.